# Is it possible to install Weblogic 12.2.1.4 on Apple M (silicon) computers?

Tags: weblogic12c, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

I've been looking for information about this, but I don't find anything. I think there's no version available at Oracle site for installing Weblogic 12.2.1.X on Apple silicon devices, but maybe it's possible to do it using Rosetta 2.

Has somebody tried it? I cannot because I don't have an Apple silicon computer yet, but I'm wondering because I still develop soft that runs on Weblogic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could, but i had to add an argument **-ignoreSysPrereqs** (for example java -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar -ignoreSysPrereqs), because throwed me a error

The error:

```
Checking if CPU speed is above 300 MHz. Actual unknown. Failed <<<<
```

I used this documentation:
https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/3888969/veridata-installation-checking-cpu-speed-failed

Answer (score 1):

I currently use different versions  (10.3.6,..)
I just copy the folder installed in an old mac with intel, an then they  work 99%, was necessary fix the folders resource like java.
..