# Can't get PlatformInfoHolder - Installing Weblogic on Mac (M1 processor)

Tags: java, weblogic12c, apple-m1

I get following error trying to instal Weblogic 12 on Mac (M1 processor)

I have set the JAVA_HOME path variable

My java version is 11

```
INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Extracting to /private/var/folders/jw/m7m77jws5kd18my9qrtp532c7khyhw/T/orcl627004433143755990.tmp.
INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Extracting the installer . . .
INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Finished self extraction to /private/var/folders/jw/m7m77jws5kd18my9qrtp532c7khyhw/T/orcl627004433143755990.tmp.
SEVERE [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.PlatformHelper - Can't get PlatformInfoHolder
SEVERE [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.PlatformHelper - Can't get PlatformInfoHolder
```

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67854232/is-it-possible-to-install-weblogic-12-2-1-4-on-apple-m1-computers) help ?

Comment: Not really @EmmanuelCollin. I've added the flag -ignoreSysPrereqs and same error have been showed

Comment: Hi @AlanHernandez, have you had any success on this? I am also struggling with the same error. In my case the -ignoreSysPrereqs was already included in command of the initial attempt.

Comment: Hello, @chegancasb it seems the issue is related to the java version. I review the logs and see this message "The OpenJDK JVM is not supported on this platform" so, if you use a non open jdk version you should be able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

After checking different options I realized that this issue only happens when I use jdk-8u381 after trying with different versions I finally solved using with previous versions, in this case is jdk-8u202, **It's probably some dependencies or anything else is different between versions**. It solved my issue BTW, im using a M2 apple chip.

The command I used is **/Users/jesus/Downloads/fmw_14.1.1.0.0_wls_lite_generic.jar**

from the path **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/bin**